# Pass parameter to MessageDialog to process it further based on user interaction with dialog

Tags: qt, qml

There is this QML message dialog:

```
MessageDialog {
            id: questionDialog
            icon: StandardIcon.Question
            standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No
            title: qsTr("Question") + editorScene.emptyString
            text: qsTr("Do stuff?") + editorScene.emptyString
            onYes: {
                console.log("I want to be able to process parameter here")
            }
            onNo: {
                console.log("Do nothing")
            }
}
```

Inside a `onParameterChanged` slot, I open the dialog while handing a `parameterChanged` signal. This signal passes a `parameter`:

```
onParameterChanged: {

 if (parameter) { // "parameter" is passed by parameterChanged signal
     questionDialog.open() // How can I pass "parameter" to dialog when opening it?
 }

}
```

Now I wonder how it is possible to pass `parameter` from `onParameterChanged` slot to question dialog to be able to process `parameter` if user selects `Yes` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using [Property Attributes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-attributes).

I defined a new `property` attribute for `MessageDialog`:

```
MessageDialog {
    id: questionDialog

    property string parameterName: ""

    onYes: {
        console.log("Parameter to be processed:", parameterName)
    }
}
```

Then I set the property attribute before opening the dialog:

```
onParameterChanged: {

    if (parameter) { // "parameter" is passed by parameterChanged signal
        questionDialog.parameterName = parameter // Set property attribute
        questionDialog.open()
    }

}
```